Closed sets on commutative topological groups
Suppose $G$ is a totally disconnected commutative topological group written additively, with a neighborhood basis $(I_\alpha)$ of $0$ of open subgroups. Why is this proof that every subgroup of $G$ closed incorrect?
Let $H$ be a group, then for every $I_\alpha$ we have that $H + I_\alpha$ is open as it can be covered with $\bigcup_{h \in H} h + I_\alpha$, hence it is also closed by open subgroups being closed.
Therefore $\bigcap_{\alpha} H + I_\alpha = H + \bigcap_{\alpha}I_\alpha = H$ is also closed.
However this does not seem true at all

That last step where you commuted a sum and an infinite intersection doesn't work. That intersection ends up computing the closure of $H$, I think.

An element of $\bigcap_{\alpha} (H+I_{\alpha})$ can be written $h_{\alpha} + i_{\alpha}$ for every $\alpha$, and all you can say about $(h_{\alpha})$ is that it converges to an element in the closure of $H$, as Qiaochu Yuan said.

That being said, I don't really know any explicit example of a nonclosed subgroup in totally disconnected commutative groups. IIRC I know there is a cardinality argument to show that they must exist.

For a Polish group $G$ and a subgroup $H\leq G$ let $$\mathrm{bor}(H,G)=\min\{\alpha\mid H \text{ is }\mathbf{\Pi}^0_\alpha\text{ in G }\},$$
so that $H$ is closed in $G$ iff $\mathrm{bor}(H,G)=1$. By a result of Solecki and Farah [1], for every uncountable Polish group $G$ and every ordinal $\alpha$ with $2<\alpha<\omega_1$, there is a subgroup $H\leq G$ with $\mathrm{bor}(H,G)=\alpha$. Applying the result to $G=2^\mathbb{N}$ shows that a totally disconnected group can have Borel subgroups of arbitrarily high complexity. I'm pretty sure one can give explicit examples of $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_3$ subgroups of $\mathbb Z^\mathbb N$ which are not closed, without invoking such a general statement, but I need to think about this for a bit longer.
As pointed  out in the comments the mistake in your argument is in swapping the infinite intersection and sum in the last line.
Edit: here is a more explicit example, consider the group $G=2^{\mathbb N\times\mathbb N}$, which is homeomorphic to the Cantor space hence totally disconnected. This is the group of infinite matrices, containing only $0$ and $1$, with addition computed cell by cell modulo $2$. Let $H$ be the subset of matrices that are eventually $0$ in every row, which is easily checked to be a subgroup of $G$. Since $$H=\{x\in 2^{\mathbb N\times\mathbb N}\mid \forall m\forall^\infty n\,\,x(m,n)=0\},$$ $H$ is $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_3$ and by Exercise 23.1 of Kechris [2], $H$ is in fact $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_3$-complete, so that it cannot be closed.
[1] Farah, Ilijas, and Sławomir Solecki. "Borel subgroups of Polish groups." Advances in Mathematics 199.2 (2006): 499-541.
[2] Kechris, Alexander. Classical descriptive set theory. Vol. 156. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.
